# Does Blender 2.8 beta support the new gtx1660

Tags: rendering, gpu, hardware

I'm thinking about buying a new PC with the recently released gtx 1660, so I want to know that is the 1660 can be used for blender 2.8 beta rendering, did anybody try it yet.

I'm a newbie in blender, so I'm sorry if this question sound stupid but I've heard that newly released GPU can have some problem with kernel (which I have no idea what it means)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about hardware. Better ask this at https://blenderartists.org

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work fine, since the GTX 1660, even though it is new, still has the same CUDA cores which blender uses for rendering. Also, all of the new RTX series cards work, meaning the GTX 1660 architecture is supported (not sure why it wouldn't be).